# How to get mathematical model from a data set with MATLAB

Tags: statistics, matlab, mathematical-modeling

I have some values imported from excel about the annual sell of a product, with 3 var, month, price, sold items I have seen how to plot a chart using curve fitting tool but I need to define a math expression that can describe the relation between these variables. How can I do this in matlab? Is there any tool that can achieve this automatically. if you look at the chart should exist a way to use an approximation that can mime the behavior(maybe with spline functions or n-point-hermit), is enough one approximated expression of the model that for the 3 var replicate a similar chart if plotted.

Comment: Hi AndreaF, while your question seems perfectly relevant here, you can also post such a question on the Computational Science forum https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ which is directly related to questions involving computational tools. Regards.

Comment: The question is way too generous. There are plenty of methods starting from simple regression to neural netwroks. And MATLAB does have functionality for quite a lot. If not, it can be implemented by oneself.

Comment: @Valery Saharov It's enough one single method in a Q&A board, isn't required to show encyclopedically all possible ways. I haven't found a way to create automatically a math expression in function of the 3 var using data analysis. If you know the answer, please help me :(

Comment: Think of you 3 variables as regressors. Pick a model (linear in parameters) and apply least squares for instance. Compute the significance marks (F-test, t-test etc.) -- a bare model is no convincing.

Comment: Why the curve fitting tool is not enough? I didn't understand.

Comment: because I need to operate algorithmically in terms of these 3 variables, so I need a math function in terms of these parameters not a chart not a generic interpolation function.